# A meromorphic function is open?

Tags: complex-analysis

I need a hint but please dont tell me that is a generalization for holomorphic functions.

Let $G$ open subset connected of $\hat{\mathbb{C}}=\mathbb{C}\cup\lbrace\infty\rbrace$ and $f:G\rightarrow\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ meromorphic function non constant. Show that $f(G)$ is open subset of $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your hint: The only potential problems is to show that $f(G)$ is a neighbourhood of $f(z)$ if $z\in G$ with either $z=\infty$ or $f(z)=\infty$ (or both). To prove it, if $z=\infty$ consider $f(1/z)$. If $f(z)=\infty$ consider $1/f(z)$. If both are true, consider $1/f(1/z)$. In all cases, use the corresponding result for holomorphic functions.

Comment: In essence what Harald has suggested is that the 'meromorphic' functions on $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ are holomorphic when you consider $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ as a complex manifold .

Comment: @JoeManlove Spot on!

Comment: For my exercise $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is the received metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Yes, and? This metric is equivalent to the standard one on $\mathbb{C}$, and moreover, inversion $z\mapsto z^{-1}$ is continuous on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ (and hence a homeomorphism, since it is its own inverse).

Comment: can you explain a little bit more the case $1/f(1/z)$ ?

Comment: @Porufes If $f$ has a pole at infinity then it has a Laurent series of the form $\sum_{k\le n} a_kz^k$ valid for large $|z|$, where $a_n\ne0$ and $n>0$. So $f(1/z)=\sum_{k\le n} a_kz^{-k}=\sum_{k\ge-n}a_{-k}z^k$ for small $|z|$. That is a pole of order $n$ at the origin. In the usual fashion, then, the reciprocal has a zero of order $n$, i.e., $1/f(1/z)=z^n g(z)$ where $g(z)=1/\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{n-k}z^k$ is analytic and nonzero in a neighbourhood of $z=0$.